# Steps to upgrade Tortoise SVN 1.9.2 to 1.9.3 without loosing previous revisions,date,messages

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

After doing some unsatisfactory research, I would really like to learn & follow **Steps to upgrade Tortoise SVN 1.9,2 to 1.9.3 without loosing previous revisions, dates, messages** etc.

It may be Simple, but I seriously don't wish to loose any of here mentioned, i.e. **Revision Numbers, Dates, Messages.**

I would really appreciate if anybody share the same and guide me to proceed further, thank you.

**[EDIT]**
The tortoise svn server is locally installed on local drive.

Comment: Revision numbers, dates, messages are ALL stored on the SVN server, tortoise SVN is just a CLIENT and you are going to keep everything because your real SVN repository is stored on a SERVER.

Comment: I've installed it locally. Not on any web server, so what would be the steps for the same? Let me put this in my question as well

Comment: You will not lose any information stored in the Subversion repository by upgrading either the server or the client. There is no risk to upgrading TortoiseSVN.

Comment: So, if I just uninstall my current tortoise svn 1.9.2 and install new 1.9.3, will it work just fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully upgraded the tortoise svn client 1.9.2 to 1.9.3

1. Before doing so, I've installed Visual SVN Server first and created a repository on the same.
2. Transferred all my current temporary repository content created by tortoise svn client to the server repository.
3. Updated the tortoise svn client and got all logs just right.

Thank you all for your support and leading me right through the process.